# IBatis sqlmap resources path working in windows not in unix

Tags: java, wildfly, mybatis

Java upgrade and wildfly upgrade for an existing code base are done. On Windows with wildfly server, the application is getting deployed properly. On Unix with wildfly server, application deployment fails as:

```
Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  
Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource ..\..\WEB-INF\lib\configs\commonSql.xml
```

**Tried** the different combinations of relative `address.Assumption` is that ibatis looks in `META-INF\classes` for the configs.

The config file has below entry:

```
sqlMap resource="..\\..\WEB-INF\lib\configs\commonSql.xml
```

Expected both windows and Unix would same Behavior with the same server.

Comment: does it work OK if the config file has forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: @NickJ It doesnt

Answer (score 1):

The usage of relative paths (and especially references to `WEB-INF` folder) in web application to access resources is not portable. And this is exactly what you faced.

The correct way to fix this depends on how you application is packed and deployed. In general you need to put resources to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of your application (or in the *.jar file in `WEB-INF/lib`). `WEB-INF/classes` together will all jars from `WEB-INF/lib` is used when iBatis searches for the resource files.

For example if you put `commonSql.xml` to `WEB-INF/classes/configs` then you need to specify this in iBatis config:

```
sqlMap resource="configs/commonSql.xml"
```

Alternatively you can create a *.jar file that contains top level folder `configs` with `commonSql.xml` file in it. Then put this *.jar file to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Then the same configuration as above will be able to load this file.